# Why does the python style guide suggest the same style for both global and local variables?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

The [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) indicates that for global variable names:

> The conventions are about the same as those for functions.

And for functions and variables it says:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
> underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

It has always perplexed me why the style guide uses the **same** convention for both local and global variable names. This almost always makes code less clear. In a language where naming conventions are very important and quite standardized, I don't understand why a different convention for locals and globals would not be recommended in the guide.

Maybe I am missing something. Does anyone know the reasoning for this?

Comment: Did you end up finding a clear namging convention? As a beginner the only thing I can think of to differentiate the two is to put global_ in front of it but surely there's a defined convention?

Answer (score 1):

When you're talking about global variables are you thinking specifically about constants? They have their own style specification (that really should be mentioned or linked in the global variables section):

> Constants
> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Comment: Understood. No, not constants. Just global variables.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know the explicit reasoning in this case for Python, it is the modern trend to not use distinct global/local naming conventions because *where* the value lives is not important. If where the value lives is important, then you should be using abstractions to get/set them instead of allowing direct, unsafe access.

If your program is properly safe and well-designed, whether or not a variable is global should have no real effect on what is happening from a programmer perspective.

Think of this from an API design perspective with the variables being endpoints that you can query. It wouldn't make much sense for the API to make visible implementation details like what file those values are stored in on the backend. As a programmer, I want to be able to do `y = ax + b` without having to wonder where all of those other variables are coming from.